# Unable to fix the bibliography. Bold question mark persists

Tags: citing

I am unable to fix the bibliographical error. The bold question mark persists. Can you please help me understand what is going on? Although the problem of the bold question mark is common and widely discussed online, a large amount of suggested fixes including on this website don't seem to help me.

[image]

And this is what I see:

[image]

My tex file is here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{verbatim}
 \usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\def\bibfont{\small}%
\def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
\def\bibhang{24pt}%
\def\newblock{\ }%
\def\BIBand{and}%


\begin{document}

I would like to cite \citep[]{Balasubramanian2004}.

\bibliographystyle{ormsv080} % outcomment this and next line in Case 1
\bibliography{LiteratureSust} % if more than one, comma separated


\end{document}
```

This is the .bib file located in the same folder as the .tex file above:

```
@ARTICLE{Aoki1997,
  AUTHOR =       "Aoki, R. and T.J. Prusa",
  TITLE =        "Sequential versus simultaneous choice with endogenous quality",
  JOURNAL =      "International Journal of Industrial Organization",
  YEAR =         "1997",
  volume =       "15",
  number =       "1",
  pages =        "103--121",
}

@ARTICLE{Balasubramanian2004,
  AUTHOR =       "Balasubramanian, S. and P. Bhardwaj",
  TITLE =        "When not all conflict is bad: Manufacturing-Marketing conflict and strategic incentive design",
  JOURNAL =      "Management Science",
  YEAR =         "2004",
  volume =       "50",
  number =       "4",
  pages =        "489--502",
}
```

These are the error messages in the log file:

[image]

Comment: Are other citations working? Do you run BibTeX? If so, is there an error message in the `.blg` file?

Comment: Your `.bib` file is definitely named `LiteratureSust.bib`? Where is `ormsv080.bst`? Is it also in the working directory?

Comment: 1) Yes- my bib file is named LiteratureSust.bib. 2) ormsv080.bst doesn't seem to matter. Any type of style returns the question mark. 3) None of the citations working. 4) Yes, BibTex. The strange part is that exactly the same code is working for another document. That is why I am so confused, why it's working in one doc but doesn't work in another.

Comment: Those are not errors. Just warnings. Look at the output from the `bibtex` run and/or the log for interesting bits.

Comment: Why does it say that the citation is unidentified?